# Is there a different xml view with "extends Fragment"?

Tags: android, xml, fragment

I'm trying to get my class XML screen but with no success,
Until now I was able to create activity, and use startActivity(activity.class)
but now there is a problem.

At the main Java file of my app i call FTDI class :

```
public void onFTDIClick(View view){
        startActivity(new Intent(this,FTDI.class));
    }
```

The FTDI class:

```
    package com.application.i;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ftdi.j2xx.D2xxManager;
import com.ftdi.j2xx.FT_Device;




public class FTDI extends Fragment{


    static Context DeviceUARTContext;
    D2xxManager ftdid2xx;
    FT_Device ftDev = null;
    int DevCount = -1;
    int currentIndex = -1;
    int openIndex = 0;

    /*graphical objects*/
    EditText readText;
    EditText writeText;
    Spinner baudSpinner;;
    Spinner stopSpinner;
    Spinner dataSpinner;
    Spinner paritySpinner;
    Spinner flowSpinner;
    Spinner portSpinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> portAdapter;

    Button configButton;
    Button openButton;
    Button readEnButton;
    Button writeButton;
    static int iEnableReadFlag = 1;

    /*local variables*/
    int baudRate; /*baud rate*/
    byte stopBit; /*1:1stop bits, 2:2 stop bits*/
    byte dataBit; /*8:8bit, 7: 7bit*/
    byte parity;  /* 0: none, 1: odd, 2: even, 3: mark, 4: space*/
    byte flowControl; /*0:none, 1: flow control(CTS,RTS)*/
    int portNumber; /*port number*/
    ArrayList<CharSequence> portNumberList;


    public static final int readLength = 512;
    public int readcount = 0;
    public int iavailable = 0;
    byte[] readData;
    char[] readDataToText;
    public boolean bReadThreadGoing = false;
    public readThread read_thread;

    boolean uart_configured = false;

    // Empty Constructor
    public FTDI()
    {
    }


    /* Constructor */
    public FTDI(Context parentContext , D2xxManager ftdid2xxContext)
    {
        DeviceUARTContext = parentContext;
        ftdid2xx = ftdid2xxContext;
    }
     public int getShownIndex() {
            return getArguments().getInt("index", 5);
        }
       @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ftdisub, container, false);

            readData = new byte[readLength];
            readDataToText = new char[readLength];

            readText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ReadValues);
            readText.setInputType(0);  

            /* by default it is 9600 */
            baudRate = 9600;

            /* default is stop bit 1 */
            stopBit = 1;

            /* default data bit is 8 bit */
            dataBit = 8;

            /* default is none */
            parity = 0;

            /* default flow control is is none */
            flowControl = 0;

            portNumber = 1; 


            return view;
       }


       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            createDeviceList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop()
        {
            disconnectFunction();
            super.onStop();
        }

        public void notifyUSBDeviceAttach()
        {
            createDeviceList();
        }

        public void notifyUSBDeviceDetach()
        {
            disconnectFunction();
        }   
        public void createDeviceList()
        {
            int tempDevCount = ftdid2xx.createDeviceInfoList(DeviceUARTContext);

            if (tempDevCount > 0)
            {
                if( DevCount != tempDevCount )
                {
                    DevCount = tempDevCount;
                updatePortNumberSelector();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DevCount = -1;
                currentIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        public void disconnectFunction()
        {
            DevCount = -1;
            currentIndex = -1;
            bReadThreadGoing = false;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(ftDev != null)
            {
                synchronized(ftDev)
                {
                    if( true == ftDev.isOpen())
                    {
                        ftDev.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public void connectFunction()
        {
            int tmpProtNumber = openIndex + 1;

            if( currentIndex != openIndex )
            {
                if(null == ftDev)
                {
                    ftDev = ftdid2xx.openByIndex(DeviceUARTContext, openIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(ftDev)
                    {
                        ftDev = ftdid2xx.openByIndex(DeviceUARTContext, openIndex);
                    }
                }
                uart_configured = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext,"Device port " + tmpProtNumber + " is already opened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if(ftDev == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext,"open device port("+tmpProtNumber+") NG, ftDev == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if (true == ftDev.isOpen())
            {
                currentIndex = openIndex;
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "open device port(" + tmpProtNumber + ") OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(false == bReadThreadGoing)
                {
                    read_thread = new readThread(handler);
                    read_thread.start();
                    bReadThreadGoing = true;
                }
            }
            else 
            {           
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "open device port(" + tmpProtNumber + ") NG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "Need to get permission!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
            }
        }


        public void updatePortNumberSelector()
        {

        }




        public void SetConfig(int baud, byte dataBits, byte stopBits, byte parity, byte flowControl)
         {
                if (ftDev.isOpen() == false) {
                    Log.e("j2xx", "SetConfig: device not open");
                    return;
                }

                // configure our port
                // reset to UART mode for 232 devices
                ftDev.setBitMode((byte) 0, D2xxManager.FT_BITMODE_RESET);

                ftDev.setBaudRate(baud);

                switch (dataBits) {
                case 7:
                    dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
                    break;
                default:
                    dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
                    break;
                }

                switch (stopBits) {
                case 1:
                    stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_2;
                    break;
                default:
                    stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
                    break;
                }

                switch (parity) {
                case 0:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_ODD;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_EVEN;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_MARK;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_SPACE;
                    break;
                default:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
                    break;
                }

                ftDev.setDataCharacteristics(dataBits, stopBits, parity);

                short flowCtrlSetting;
                switch (flowControl) {
                case 0:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_DTR_DSR;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_XON_XOFF;
                    break;
                default:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
                    break;
                }

                // TODO : flow ctrl: XOFF/XOM
                // TODO : flow ctrl: XOFF/XOM
                ftDev.setFlowControl(flowCtrlSetting, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x0d);

                uart_configured = true;
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "Config done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         public void EnableRead (){     
                iEnableReadFlag = (iEnableReadFlag + 1)%2;

                if(iEnableReadFlag == 1) {
                    ftDev.purge((byte) (D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_TX));
                    ftDev.restartInTask();
                    readEnButton.setText("Read Enabled");
                }
                else{
                    ftDev.stopInTask();
                    readEnButton.setText("Read Disabled");
                }
            }
         final Handler handler =  new Handler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                {
                    if(iavailable > 0)
                    {
                        readText.append(String.copyValueOf(readDataToText, 0, iavailable));
                    }
                }
            };
            private class readThread  extends Thread
            {
                Handler mHandler;

                readThread(Handler h){
                    mHandler = h;
                    this.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                }

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    int i;

                    while(true == bReadThreadGoing)
                    {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }

                        synchronized(ftDev)
                        {
                            iavailable = ftDev.getQueueStatus();                
                            if (iavailable > 0) {

                                if(iavailable > readLength){
                                    iavailable = readLength;
                                }

                                ftDev.read(readData, iavailable);
                                for (i = 0; i < iavailable; i++) {
                                    readDataToText[i] = (char) readData[i];
                                }
                                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DevCount = 0;
        createDeviceList();
        if(DevCount > 0)
        {
            connectFunction();
            SetConfig(baudRate, dataBit, stopBit, parity, flowControl);
        }       
    }
}
```

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"

        android:id="@+id/PITCHING"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
  <TextView android:text = "Read Bytes" 
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ReadBytes"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ReadValues"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="#708070"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            />



                    <Button android:id="@+id/readEnButton"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"

                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Read Enabled"
                    />              
</LinearLayout>
```

At the manifest file:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".FTDI"
            android:label="Reading Circuit Data"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        </activity>
```

Until now i used , before working with Frgment:

```
package com.application.i;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class FTDI extends Activity 
{
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ftdisub);

}
}
```

As i press the button on my main screen it stuck, the hole application finished with error.

Edit:
My problem is that I need a UI to check this class and then to put it as a `Service`, I know how to `Service` it, without user interface.
I changed the code to be an `activity` and it looks :

```
package com.application.i;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.ftdi.j2xx.D2xxManager;
import com.ftdi.j2xx.FT_Device;




public class FTDI extends Activity{


    static Context DeviceUARTContext;
    D2xxManager ftdid2xx;
    FT_Device ftDev = null;
    int DevCount = -1;
    int currentIndex = -1;
    int openIndex = 0;

    /*graphical objects*/
    EditText readText;
    EditText writeText;
    Spinner baudSpinner;;
    Spinner stopSpinner;
    Spinner dataSpinner;
    Spinner paritySpinner;
    Spinner flowSpinner;
    Spinner portSpinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> portAdapter;

    Button configButton;
    Button openButton;
    Button readEnButton;
    Button writeButton;
    static int iEnableReadFlag = 1;

    /*local variables*/
    int baudRate; /*baud rate*/
    byte stopBit; /*1:1stop bits, 2:2 stop bits*/
    byte dataBit; /*8:8bit, 7: 7bit*/
    byte parity;  /* 0: none, 1: odd, 2: even, 3: mark, 4: space*/
    byte flowControl; /*0:none, 1: flow control(CTS,RTS)*/
    int portNumber; /*port number*/
    ArrayList<CharSequence> portNumberList;


    public static final int readLength = 512;
    public int readcount = 0;
    public int iavailable = 0;
    byte[] readData;
    char[] readDataToText;
    public boolean bReadThreadGoing = false;
    public readThread read_thread;

    boolean uart_configured = false;

    // Empty Constructor
    public FTDI()
    {
    }


    /* Constructor */
    public FTDI(Context parentContext , D2xxManager ftdid2xxContext)
    {
        DeviceUARTContext = parentContext;
        ftdid2xx = ftdid2xxContext;
    }
//   public int getShownIndex() {
//          return getArguments().getInt("index", 5);
//      }
//     @Override
//      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
//          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//          if (container == null) {
//              return null;
//          }
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ftdisub);



//          View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ftdisub, container, false);

            readData = new byte[readLength];
            readDataToText = new char[readLength];

            readText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ReadValues);
            readText.setInputType(0);  

            /* by default it is 9600 */
            baudRate = 9600;

            /* default is stop bit 1 */
            stopBit = 1;

            /* default data bit is 8 bit */
            dataBit = 8;

            /* default is none */
            parity = 0;

            /* default flow control is is none */
            flowControl = 0;

            portNumber = 1; 



       }


//     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//          super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
//
//      }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            createDeviceList();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop()
        {
            disconnectFunction();
            super.onStop();
        }

        public void notifyUSBDeviceAttach()
        {
            createDeviceList();
        }

        public void notifyUSBDeviceDetach()
        {
            disconnectFunction();
        }   
        public void createDeviceList()
        {
            int tempDevCount = ftdid2xx.createDeviceInfoList(DeviceUARTContext);

            if (tempDevCount > 0)
            {
                if( DevCount != tempDevCount )
                {
                    DevCount = tempDevCount;
                updatePortNumberSelector();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DevCount = -1;
                currentIndex = -1;
            }
        }

        public void disconnectFunction()
        {
            DevCount = -1;
            currentIndex = -1;
            bReadThreadGoing = false;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(ftDev != null)
            {
                synchronized(ftDev)
                {
                    if( true == ftDev.isOpen())
                    {
                        ftDev.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        public void connectFunction()
        {
            int tmpProtNumber = openIndex + 1;

            if( currentIndex != openIndex )
            {
                if(null == ftDev)
                {
                    ftDev = ftdid2xx.openByIndex(DeviceUARTContext, openIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    synchronized(ftDev)
                    {
                        ftDev = ftdid2xx.openByIndex(DeviceUARTContext, openIndex);
                    }
                }
                uart_configured = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext,"Device port " + tmpProtNumber + " is already opened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if(ftDev == null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext,"open device port("+tmpProtNumber+") NG, ftDev == null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            if (true == ftDev.isOpen())
            {
                currentIndex = openIndex;
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "open device port(" + tmpProtNumber + ") OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(false == bReadThreadGoing)
                {
                    read_thread = new readThread(handler);
                    read_thread.start();
                    bReadThreadGoing = true;
                }
            }
            else 
            {           
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "open device port(" + tmpProtNumber + ") NG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "Need to get permission!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
            }
        }


        public void updatePortNumberSelector()
        {

        }




        public void SetConfig(int baud, byte dataBits, byte stopBits, byte parity, byte flowControl)
         {
                if (ftDev.isOpen() == false) {
                    Log.e("j2xx", "SetConfig: device not open");
                    return;
                }

                // configure our port
                // reset to UART mode for 232 devices
                ftDev.setBitMode((byte) 0, D2xxManager.FT_BITMODE_RESET);

                ftDev.setBaudRate(baud);

                switch (dataBits) {
                case 7:
                    dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
                    break;
                default:
                    dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
                    break;
                }

                switch (stopBits) {
                case 1:
                    stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_2;
                    break;
                default:
                    stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
                    break;
                }

                switch (parity) {
                case 0:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_ODD;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_EVEN;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_MARK;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_SPACE;
                    break;
                default:
                    parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
                    break;
                }

                ftDev.setDataCharacteristics(dataBits, stopBits, parity);

                short flowCtrlSetting;
                switch (flowControl) {
                case 0:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_DTR_DSR;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_XON_XOFF;
                    break;
                default:
                    flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
                    break;
                }

                // TODO : flow ctrl: XOFF/XOM
                // TODO : flow ctrl: XOFF/XOM
                ftDev.setFlowControl(flowCtrlSetting, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x0d);

                uart_configured = true;
                Toast.makeText(DeviceUARTContext, "Config done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         public void EnableRead (){     
                iEnableReadFlag = (iEnableReadFlag + 1)%2;

                if(iEnableReadFlag == 1) {
                    ftDev.purge((byte) (D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_TX));
                    ftDev.restartInTask();
                    readEnButton.setText("Read Enabled");
                }
                else{
                    ftDev.stopInTask();
                    readEnButton.setText("Read Disabled");
                }
            }
         final Handler handler =  new Handler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg)
                {
                    if(iavailable > 0)
                    {
                        readText.append(String.copyValueOf(readDataToText, 0, iavailable));
                    }
                }
            };
            private class readThread  extends Thread
            {
                Handler mHandler;

                readThread(Handler h){
                    mHandler = h;
                    this.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                }

                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    int i;

                    while(true == bReadThreadGoing)
                    {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        }

                        synchronized(ftDev)
                        {
                            iavailable = ftDev.getQueueStatus();                
                            if (iavailable > 0) {

                                if(iavailable > readLength){
                                    iavailable = readLength;
                                }

                                ftDev.read(readData, iavailable);
                                for (i = 0; i < iavailable; i++) {
                                    readDataToText[i] = (char) readData[i];
                                }
                                Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                                mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DevCount = 0;
        createDeviceList();
        if(DevCount > 0)
        {
            connectFunction();
            SetConfig(baudRate, dataBit, stopBit, parity, flowControl);
        }       
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A `Fragment` needs to be attached to a `Activity`. You can't just change `extends Activity` to `extends Fragment` and expect everything to be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To attach a fragment to an Activity you have two ways:

1) Declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.

2) Programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup.

In my opinion you can use the second way, so basically you need a ViewGroup in the activity where to put the Fragment; something like a Layout can be good for that. 
When you have the place where to insert the Fragment you can insert it using the LayoutInfleter.

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
getLayoutInflater.inflate(R.id.youLayoutContainer, fragment, false);
```

Take a look at the page below for more informations:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, from the link you posted i understood that i do not need this `Fregment`, just an Activity, so i deleted `onCreateView`, `inflater.inflate` , `getShownIndex`, `onActivityCreated`. And put `onCreate` as i was doing until now. Still I get this problem, do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: can you please update the code on the page with your new one? and what is exactly the problem?

Comment: I updated it, you can see it under "Edit:" also the problem

Comment: I see many strange things in your code. First of all you DO NOT have to override Class constructor in you Activity. You neved say new Activity! So basically the only way to start Activities is using Intent (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). Second thing I see a class extending Fragment, so are you using fragment or are you not?

Comment: I know how to set an activity, i changed the hole thing, now its working.